# How to create one to many and one to one at the same time EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In plain english:

Room (Principle entity) has a RoomPrice (Dependent entity). This seems to be a one to one relationship. However, I also would like to keep the history of the Room Price changes.

When I create one to one relationship the ef core migration creates an obviously unique index to ensure that not many RoomPrice is created for the same room.

Somehow, I actually want to be able to create multiple Room prices for a single room (and keep the history) but only one of the RoomPrices can be referenced to room.

So something like this:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public RoomPrice RoomPrice { get; set; } // current room price
    public int? RoomPriceId { get; set; } // current room price id
    public ICollection<RoomPrices> RoomPrices { get; set; }
}

public class RoomPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
}
```

But somehow the above migration works to create the table. However, Adding new room throws the following exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Rooms_RoomPrices_RoomPriceId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "test", table "dbo.RoomPrices", column 'Id'.

Is there any definition for this in ef core? And How can I set up this relationship in fluent api or with data annotation?

Or I totally got this wrong and I should just implement a one to many relationship and get the latest entry by the CreationTime as a active/current room price for the room?

Comment: It seems like you really want price to be an attribute of the room, then keep a history of versions of the same room. You’d have a complex key, with some sort of ID plus date stamp to identify each version of the room. This is probably more advanced of a scenario than is ordinarily supported off the shelf.

Comment: I managed to get it work by breaking the transactions. First unit of work creates the Room with Null room price. Second transaction adds the Room Price and then updates the Room attribute to set RoomPrice.